# workbox-webpack-plugin's InjectManifest only works with `devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: 'file:///[absolute-resource-path]'`

Tags: webpack, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I want to use `workbox-webpack-plugin` to include my own service worker. However, using `InjectManifest` doesn't work unless I use the output option `devToolModuleFilenameTemplate`.
It seems `library: "[name]"` is the failing configuration in combination with the `workbox-webpack-plugin`. Why do I have to set `devToolModuleFilenameTemplate` when using `library: "[name]"` option?

#### Minimal project to reproduce the error

https://gitlab.com/d.kuhnke/workbox-webpack-plugin-problem

#### NPM depedencies

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.31.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.7.3",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.1.2"
  }
```

#### Failing config (`webpack.common.js` / `webpack.prod.js`)

```js
const path = require('path');
const { InjectManifest } = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        Test: './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: "[name]", // this is the line which makes problems
        clean: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new InjectManifest({
            swSrc: './src/test-offline-worker.js'
        }),
    ],
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: ['dist', '**/node_modules']
    },
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map', // production source map
};
```

#### Working config (`webpack.dev.js`)

```js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

const path = require('path');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    output: { // InjectManifest only works with this setting
        devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: 'file:///[absolute-resource-path]'  // map to source with absolute file path not webpack:// protocol
    },
});
```

#### Error message of failing config

```
PS C:\Users\USERNAME\dev\git\personal\webpack-problem> npm run build:prod

> webpack-problem@1.0.0 build:prod
> webpack --config webpack.prod.js

asset Test.bundle.js 618 bytes [compared for emit] (name: Test) 1 related asset
asset test-offline-worker.js 300 bytes [emitted] 1 related asset
./src/index.js 1 bytes [built] [code generated]

ERROR in Invalid URL: webpack://[name]/./src/test-offline-worker.js

webpack 5.31.2 compiled with 1 error in 104 ms
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\USERNAME\dev\git\personal\webpack-problem
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c webpack --config webpack.prod.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USERNAME\scoop\persist\nodejs\cache\_logs\2021-04-12T14_28_43_806Z-debug.log
```

### Update (2021-05-18)

As Jeff Posnick explained the problem is missing replacement of the placeholder string `[name]`. A solution / workaround is to set the `output.devtoolNamespace` to a constant value as described [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9570#issuecomment-520713006).

Comment: Apologies; I'm tracking this along with a few related issues at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2729

Comment: Actually, I've revisited this since it seems distinct from a few other problems mentioned in the GitHub issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things at play here.

First, `webpack`'s sourcemap generator doesn't seem to work properly when [`output.library`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary) is set to `'[name]'`, independent of anything having to do with Workbox:

If you comment out the `InjectManifest` plugin from your "failing config" example, then it will produce a sourcemap that contains:

`{"sources":["webpack://[name]/./src/index.js"], ...}`

which I don't believe is valid either. It doesn't trigger a compilation error, but it's not the expected output. That would be an issue to raise with the `webpack` team.

Second, I can't think of a valid use case for when you'd add the `InjectManifest` plugin to a compilation that produced library output. The service worker created with `InjectManfest` is supposed to precache the output of a given compilation, but at the same time, the output of a compilation with `output.library` set is meant to be a reusable library that others will pull in from their own codebase, i.e. something suitable for releasing on `npm`. It does not make sense to ship a service worker alongside that library, or anything like that.

Comment: Our webpack build contains multiple websites. The libraries are used to package the necessary dependencies for the websites and are only used internally. Some websites require caching to support non-stable mobile internet connections. For these we are using the `InjectManifest` plugin. However, the websites were only added recently, so maybe our current webpack setup is not appriopriate anymore.

Comment: If there are websites that require caching, you should add the `InjectManifest` plugin to the compilations for those websites (which presumably consume your `library`), not to the compilation that produces the `library` output.